# O que aconteceu com a recompensa nessa pergunta?

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, pergunta-específica, recompensa

A pergunta [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101) foi respondida por mim e a resposta recebeu votos. Tempos depois o AP colocou uma recompensa. Aparentemente ele esqueceu de de atribui para a resposta manualmente. Até onde eu sei a recompensa deveria ser atribuída automaticamente em 50% para a resposta mais votada com pelo menos 2 votos, que era o caso da minha resposta (a única). A resposta já tinha uma aceitação, então a recompensa deveria ser dada por completo. Veja o [*timeline*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/55118/timeline).

> Se você não conceder sua gratificação dentro de 7 dias (mais o período de tolerância), a resposta mais votada criada após o início da gratificação com uma pontuação mínima de 2 será recompensada com a metade do valor da gratificação. Se nenhuma resposta corresponder a esses critérios, a gratificação não será concedida a ninguém.
>
> Se a gratificação foi iniciada pelo proprietário da pergunta e este aceitar uma resposta publicada durante o período de gratificação, e a gratificação expirar sem uma concessão explícita, consideraremos que o proprietário da gratificação gostou da resposta aceita e concederemos o valor total da gratificação no momento em que esta expirar.

Não foi atribuído. Há algum motivo para isto, ou será *bug*?

Se é *bug* pode ter acontecido em outros locais? O AP não percebeu e eu só percebi por pura sorte.

Parece que o Guilherme matou nos comentários. Então existe alguma coisa que possa ser feita já que a intenção dele era que a recompensa fosse dada à resposta postada?

Comment: De fato me recordo de ter posto um recompensa como "Uma ou mais respostas são excepcionais e merecem recompensa adicional.", e não ter o feito manual, pois como diz o citado "o proprietário da gratificação gostou da resposta aceita e concederemos o valor total da gratificação no momento em que esta expirar." assim o sistema se encarregaria de o fazer.

Comment: Creio que o problema possa estar aqui "a resposta mais votada **criada após o início da gratificação** com uma pontuação mínima de 2 será recompensada com a metade do valor da gratificação." , "Se a gratificação foi iniciada pelo proprietário da pergunta e este **aceitar uma resposta publicada durante o período de gratificação**", ambas não se enquadram, pois eu ja havia aceitado a resposta e já faze algum tempo, so entao ofereci a gratificação.

Comment: Contudo creio que esta logica poderia ser revista.

Comment: É verdade, pode ser isto mesmo.

Comment: Eu posso por outra e marcar dessa vez, se você quiser, afinal, pra mim pouco importa os pontos, o que vale é o conteúdo :D

Comment: Vamos aguardar. Depois o critério é seu. Eu gosto dos pontos, mas não ligo tanto. Eu não acho justo você ter que recompensar duas vezes, ainda mais que mesmo depois de por a recompensa, houve pouco reconhecimento da pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A sua resposta foi postada e aceita bem antes de a recompensa ser colocada na pergunta, por isso não está apta a receber os pontos automaticamente. Talvez tenha problemas no nosso FAQ em português, ver as explicações em inglês em [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: E não tem nada que possa ser feito agora?

Comment: Em relação aos pontos? Não. Ou em relação ao help e ao faq?

Comment: Ambos. :) É uma pena, já que a intenção era outra. Tem muita coisa muito confusa, inclusive em inglês. As descrições das medalhas precisa contratar um personal NASA scientist para entender como ganha :D

Comment: De repente a gente pode esclarecer dúvidas sobre as medalhas aqui: http://space.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: De meu ponto de vista tem muita coisa com problemas de ambiguidade, na qual diferente usuário leem e tem intendimentos diferentes.